# A clean way to write loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

here I get ordered array of weekdays. It works ok for me, but looks terribly. Pure rubbish ). Is there (I am sure there is one) any way to refactor it ?(to look cleaner?)

```
  def weekdays
    (deduct_weekdays.map{|day| day.strftime("%A")}).reverse!
  end

  private
  def deduct_weekdays
  arr = []
  @n = 0
  7.times do 
    arr << DateTime.now - @n      
    @n += 1
  end
  arr
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What about like this?

```
require 'date'

def deduct_weekdays
  arr = []
  n = 0
  7.times do 
    arr << (Date.today - n).strftime("%A")
    n += 1
  end
  arr.reverse!
end

# returns:
["Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday"]
```

It returns the same result as above, but only 1 iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
(6.days.ago.to_date..Date.today).collect{|d|d.strftime('%A')}
```